# Google Play : transfer of an app signed with the same app key as my other apps

Tags: java, android, google-play, code-signing

I sign all my apps with the same app signing key.

If I want to transfer my app to another developer, I understand that I will have to transfer my signing key to this developer (=> key compromised)

So, I wonder if a good solution would be to activate 'Google Play App Signing' https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423  for this app in order to upload the key to Google so that it is kept safe by Google and the third party developer has no direct access to it (he could use it to sign indirectly the transferred app (Google performs the signature) but could not download the key).

Is it a good idea ?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like the best way out of a bad situation. But for any future readers, this is one reason why signing all your apps with a single key isn't ideal.